# What is the expected UX for android apps that require MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-external-storage

My current Android application employs jetpack compose and requires the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to be granted.

My application has the following code to start activity for result and allow the user to grant this permission:-

```
 val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
         // What should I expect to code here?
        }
```

I request the permission on a button click as shown here:-

```
 val uri = Uri.parse("package:$myPackageName")

        Button(
            onClick = {
                launcher.launch(Intent(ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, uri))
            }
        ) {

        }
```

My issue is that the user has to navigate back to my application once they have enabled full file access, therefore the result I receive in the callback is always

```
ActivityResult{resultCode=RESULT_CANCELED, data=null}
```

I then have to check whether or not the user has granted permission using

```
Environment.isExternalStorageManager()
```

is there no other alternative?

is there any method the user can employ that returns the result from the settings screen where they enable the permission itself?

Comment: I do not understand the subject of your post.

Comment: `issue is that the user has to navigate back to my application once they have enabled full file access,` They will close the settings window and then your activity will be the top one again. Navigate?

Comment: @blackapps for this use case the call back result is always the same, as the user has to navigate BACK into my application, which makes the result redundant, an improvement would be if when the user enables all file access that action navigates the user FORWARD and the call back result could then contain a meaningful value, informing me the user had granted access. as it stands this user experience feels "Klunky" as the user has to use the Up/ back navigation buttons

Comment: The result code is always zero. And there is no further info. That is indeed pretty bad. But navigating back? I dont understand and i said before that if settings window is closed you come back in the calling activity. What would there be to navigate? Second time i ask.